# highcharts, used an array but data doesnt show

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net, jquery

i am trying to add some data into highcharts, am using vb.net made a datatable, and linked to array, in javascript i have a hidden field, everything works, but it doesnt show the data!!

code in javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var a = $("#hidden").val();  
   var array = JSON.parse(a)
   }

  </script>
 {
     series: [{
               name: 'June',
               data: array 
           },
```

the data is not showing up, when debugging it shows that the "array " has data, but its not comming up on the chart.

i have heard that i need to put the array into an int, in order to show it on the chart...

the debugger shows when i hover on the 'array'

---

```
 Array[18]
 0: "2005"
 1: "0"
 2: "0"
 3: "0"
 4: "0"
 5: "0"
 6: "0"
 7: "0"
 8: "0"
 9: "0"
 10: "0"
 11: "0"
 12: "9000"
 13: "9000"
 14: "0"
 15: "0"
 16: "0"
 17: "0"
 length: 18
 __proto__: Array[0]
 -----------------
```

which is getting from the datatables in vb.net

Comment: What is the type of your array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array is wrong.

```
 series: [{
           name: 'June',
           data: array 
       },
```

check this again